# taking the gradient of huber loss in theano

Tags: statistics, theano, gradient-descent

I have two functions that are suppose to produce equal results: `f1(x,theta)=f2(x,theta)`.

Given input `x`, I need to find the parameters `theta` that makes this equality hold as well as possible.

Initially I was thinking of using squared loss and minimizing `(f1(x,theta)-f2(x,theta))^2` and solving via SGD.

However I was thinking of making the loss more precise and using huber (or absolute loss) of the difference.
Huber loss is a piecewise function (ie initially it is quadratic and then it changes into a linear function).

How can I take the gradient of my huber loss in theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty simple implementation of huber loss in theano can be found [here](http://breze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specify.html)

Here is a code snippet

```
import theano.tensor as T
delta = 0.1
def huber(target, output):
    d = target - output
    a = .5 * d**2
    b = delta * (abs(d) - delta / 2.)
    l = T.switch(abs(d) <= delta, a, b)
    return l.sum()
```

The function `huber` will return a symbolic representation of the loss which you can then plug in `theano.tensor.grad` to get the gradient and use it to minimize using SGD